# If $A$ and $B$ are two unit rings then $\,(A\times B)^*=A^*\times B^*\;?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$(A\times B)^*$ are the units of $A\times B$ and $A^*\times B^*$ are the units of $A$ (Cartesian product) the units of $B$.

I found an example that works well, that is, it satisfies the equality, but to demonstrate it I need to generalize it and I don’t know how.

Could someone help me please.

Comment: Please format your math using MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if $(x,y)$ is invertible in $R \times S$, say $(u , v)$ is the inverse, then $xu = 1_R, yv=1_S$, so $x$ and $y$ are both invertible.

If  $x$ is invertible and $y$ is invertible , then $(x, y) * (x^{-1} , y^{-1}) = (1_R, 1_S)$, so $(x^{-1} , y^{-1})$ is an inverse.